# R Can't render small font in a PDF file

Tags: r, pdf

I am creating very complex plots in R with very tiny text such as `cex=0.04` or smaller. But I found small fonts are not rendered at all after a certain font size. How can I display tiny letters?

```
pdf(file = paste("R_Plot_", format(Sys.time(), "%Y_%m%e_%H%M_%S"), ".pdf",sep=""),
    width = 11, height = 8)  
pMar = 0
par(mar = c(pMar,pMar,pMar,pMar)) 
lenM = 10
dimSq = lenM * lenM
layout(matrix(seq(1,dimSq), lenM,lenM))
for(i in 1:dimSq){
  plot(0,0, yaxt = 'n', xaxt='n', ann=FALSE, cex=0)
  tSize = i / dimSq
  text(0,0, labels=paste("cex=",tSize), cex=tSize )
}
dev.off()
```

[image: Imgur]

The code above can produce a PDF file like this (I don't have enough reputation to post an image), with unintentional blank cells.

Comment: I wonder if it's not a problem with pdf viewers; if I write this to an eps file and inspect the content in a text editor, the text is there, just not displayed.

Comment: @baptiste I get nothing for the very small `cex` using `pdf`. No matter the viewer/editor i use, the text isn't there. Using `postscript()` to write the file, the text is written, but it doesn't appear to have the correct size for the smallest.

Comment: Right, there seems to be threshold below which the pdf device won't even write the text command in the file. I tried to find it in grDevices, but didn't. As a workaround, you could scale everything else up, I guess

Comment: [maybe this line is to blame](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/grDevices/src/devPS.c#L7759), for cex*ps (whatever that is, 72?) smaller than 0.5, size becomes 0, and [produces no output.](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/grDevices/src/devPS.c#L7763). Probably a question for R-devel.

Comment: The problem seems to be bigger than I could handle. But following @baptiste 's advice to scale everything up by 2, I was able to reduce the number of the blank cells from 6 to 3. I guess I could scale it up by even a bigger number as a temporal solution.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be trying package 'Cairo'

[Cairo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html): R graphics device using cairo graphics library for creating **high-quality bitmap (PNG, JPEG, TIFF), vector (PDF, SVG, PostScript) and display (X11 and Win32) output**.

and then use the function which is similar to pdf()

```
    CairoPDF()
```

Comment: This solution with Cairo perfectly worked for my case. Thanks!